# AFNetworking and compex JSON structures

Tags: objective-c, json, afnetworking

I'm writing a native application for iPhone, I'm quite new to the subject.
Using AFNetworking I request (with POST) and process the JSON reply.
But I've noticed that once the JSON response is more complex:

```
{
    "isFound": "YES",
    "timestamp": "2013-06-12 22:46:47",
    "screenTitle": "Perla Review",
    "placeName": "Perla",
    "placeUniqueId": "101",
    "placeCategory": "PUB",
    "username": "@jim",
    "userImgURL": "",
    "gender": "male",
    "infoMsg": "TBD",
    "youLike": "Like",
    "likesInfoMsg": "",
    "revInfoList": [
        {
            "type": 0,
            "data": "",
            "text": ""
        },
        {
            "type": 1,
            "data": "2",
            "text": ""
        },
        {
            "type": 2,
            "data": "3",
            "text": ""
        }
    ],
    "commentsList": []
}
```

Then AFNetworking fails to read and construct the sub arrays (revInfoList & commentsList).
Am I doing something wrong, or AFNetworking does not support such json structures?
Here is my objective C code to request the data and process the reply:

```
static NSString *const myAPIBaseURL = @"http://somedomain.com/api/";

NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:myAPIBaseURL]];
NSString *reqPath = @"review/review_fullinfo";

// prepare params
NSString *reqData_loginUsername = [[[Storage_Modal alloc] init] getLoginUsername];
NSString *reqData_currentCoordinatesLat = [[NSNumber numberWithDouble:[appDelegateInst.myCurrentLocation coordinate].latitude] stringValue];
NSString *reqData_currentCoordinatesLon = [[NSNumber numberWithDouble:[appDelegateInst.myCurrentLocation coordinate].longitude] stringValue];

NSString *reqData_reviewUniqueId = reviewUniqueId;

NSDictionary *parameters = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            @"json", @"format",
                            reqData_loginUsername, @"loginUsername",
                            reqData_currentCoordinatesLat, @"currentCoordinatesLatitude",
                            reqData_currentCoordinatesLon, @"currentCoordinatesLongitude",
                            reqData_reviewUniqueId, @"reviewUniqueId",
                            nil];

AFHTTPClient *client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL];
[client registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];
[client setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"];

[client postPath:reqPath parameters:parameters 
     success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        NSDictionary *xxx = responseObject;
        // 'xxx' contains all the top level keys and values, but the sub arrays are empty... why?

     }
     failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

         NSLog(@"SERVER ERROR: %@", error);
     }
```

**NOTE: Please forgive me if there is a syntax error in the objective-C code, I had to collect the code from multiple functions.
Thank you.

Comment: You should show us what code you are using to access revInfoList and commentsList. It is not clear from what you've shown that these two lists are really empty as your comment suggests

Comment: @TimDean I'm looking at the `responseObject` in the DEBUG. I see the `revInfoList` key and under it 3 empty arrays. So the problem seems to be more basic than the code that accesses the keys.

Comment: The fact that you see 3 "empty" arrays says to me that the JSON parser is doing something correctly here (since you have 3 children under revInfolist). They should be NSDictionary objects and not NSArray object, so I'm wondering what EXACTLY you are seeing in "the DEBUG" (I presume you mean you're looking it at it in the debugger in XCode). Does it show 3 objects of type NSArray that happen to be empty? Depending on how you are looking at it in the debugger, it is possible that it is not actually 3 empty arrays at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFNetworking uses [NSJSONSerialization](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to convert your JSON into a Foundation object, usually an NSDictionary or NSArray.  NSJSONSerialization conforms strictly to [RFC 4627](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt).

The JSON response you've posted is valid JSON, so there are only 3 causes I can think of for the behavior you describe:

1. Your server is returning a different payload than the one you posted here
2. Your server is encoding the payload incorrectly
3. You're incorrect about what the `xxx` NSDictionary contains

You can test #1 by looking at your `AFJSONRequestOperation`'s `responseString` and `responseData` properties.  #2 and #3 can both be tested by inspecting the `xxx` object carefully.  If you post the output of these objects here, we can help you diagnose better.

Your AFNetworking code and your expected JSON both look fine, so I don't think it's an issue with AFNetworking.

Comment: Thank you for the insight. Once I've started going through the steps I've discovered the issue. As you said, everything should work, and it does. It is only once I've printed the description of `responseString` I've noticed that the XCode debugger is the source of my wasted time. Everything is there, but the debugger is just too damn buggy to show all the info. When I print the description of `xxx` it's all there. I've learned something new. Thank you so much :)

Comment: That's weird.  You might want to post a separate question about that.  You might look at your setting for "Optimization Level" in your target's Build Settings - if it's not set to "none" the compiler might be throwing out data that it knows will never be accessed.  I recommend leaving this set to "none" during debugging.